# Why does "hostname -i" return "Unknown host"?

Tags: hostname, ip-address, amazon-linux

We have created an AWS EC2 instance using AMI type `Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0.20190514 x86_64 HVM`.

After we started up the instance, our software printed out an IP address error.  When we tried running the command `hostname -i`, it returned `hostname: Unknown host`.

The `hostname` command by itself returns the correct hostname, and the `ifconfig` command shows `eth0` having the correct IP address.

Our `/etc/hosts` file contained:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

We ended up changing that to contain:

```
<ip address>   localhost <hostname>
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

After that, `hostname -i` returned the IP address.  But we would rather not have to make that change to `/etc/hosts`, because we looked at another team's EC2 instance running the exact same AMI type, and their `/etc/hosts` file contains:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Running `hostname -i` on their instance returns the correct IP address, and it looks like they didn't have to edit their `/etc/hosts` file.

Why does `hostname -i` return `Unknown host` on our instance?

Comment: The man page for `hostname` recommends not using `-i` but to use `--all-ip-addresses` instead as this option does not depend on DNS resolution. How does `hostname --all-ip-addresses` work on your instance?

Comment: @doneal24 That prints out the correct IP address.

Answer (score 1):

`hostname -i` uses DNS resolution to get your IP. If you are getting that error it means that your machine's hostname is not correctly configured. By default, your machine get's it's hostname along with it's Private IP address from your VPC's DHCP service. In Amazon Linux, if you want to revert back to the default set up make sure of the following:

1. Your `/etc/sysconfig/network` must look like this (this is likely where your issue lies):

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

2. Your `/etc/hosts` must look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Make sure to reboot your server to apply these changes. If you are using a custom hostname then you will have to set a static hostname for your instance and you can do this as follows (assuming your domain is "example.com" and the host for this machine is "server":

1. Your `/etc/sysconfig/network` must look like this:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server.example.com
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

2. Your `/etc/hosts` must look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
<instance-private-ip>   server server.example.com
```

Make sure to reboot your server and when you run the command `hostname`, it should print out `server.example.com` and your should get your private IP when you run the command `hostname -i`.

For more information on the DHCP and how it works in VPC, refer to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html).